# Power BI Matrix Totals calculating incorrectly for

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, measure

I am currently having an issue with the power bi Matrix Calculation when using dax. I need to calculate the Running total for overtime per fortnight, which I have achieved using the following

```
Lieu running total to Date = CALCULATE(SUM('Table1'[OT]),FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Calendar'[Date]),ISONORAFTER('Calendar'[Date], MAX('Calendar'[Date]), DESC)))
```

However I now need to calculate the excess hours (OT) which I have used the following to calculate people over 90 hours(additional 10 hours)

```
Excess Lieu2 = IF([Lieu running total in Date]>=160,[Lieu running total in Date]-160,0)
```

The issues is the the grand totals is calculating the entire total - 160

[image]

The the last few total rows as well as the grand total are aggregating incorrectly...ANy help is greatly appreciated. A Dax solution is needed as this will need to be dynamic as the employees names will be added

Answer (score 0):

Add a new measure with below code and add that measure to your matrix.

```
Total_Lieu_running_total_to_Date =
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        table,//add the table from which the pay period end date is coming
        table[pay period end date],//date column which you are using in matrix
        "Lieu_running_total_to_Date", 
    [Lieu running total to Date] //measure which you using currently
    ),
    [Lieu_running_total_to_Date]
)
```

Note:- Please add some sample data so it would help other to give you solution quickly.